# WINEXE + run CLI command on WIN from linux machine

Tags: linux, windows-xp, remote-access, remote-control

I use the winexe tool in order to run cli command on my WIN xp from Linux machine

as the following example ( from my Linux )

- 10.18.15.132 - IP of the WIN XP machine

  ```
   ./winexe -U  Cellcom/SDnet%w5frdlpp  //10.18.15.132 "ipconfig"
  ```

Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Cellcom
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.18.15.132
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.18.15.0
```

but today when I run the winexe I got the following error?

```
   ./winexe -U  Cellcom/SDnet%w5frdlpp  //10.18.15.132 "ipconfig"


    ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT
```

after 1/2 hour I run the winexe again and now its ok

So I don’t understand why I get "status account lock" for 1/2 hour ??

- What could be the problem, and if I get lock how to un-lock?
- what’s the steps that should be done in order to unlock ??

WINEXE info

```
  winexe version 1.00
  This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPLv3
  Usage: winexe [-?] [-?] [-?] [-?NP] [-?NPV] [-?|--help] [--usage] [-d|--debuglevel     DEBUGLEVEL]
      [--debug-stderr] [-s|--configfile CONFIGFILE] [--option=name=value]
      [-l|--log-basename LOGFILEBASE] [--leak-report] [--leak-report-full]
      [-R|--name-resolve NAME-RESOLVE-ORDER]
      [-O|--socket-options SOCKETOPTIONS] [-n|--netbiosname NETBIOSNAME]
      [-S|--signing on|off|required] [-W|--workgroup WORKGROUP]
      [--realm=REALM] [-i|--scope SCOPE] [-m|--maxprotocol MAXPROTOCOL]
      [-U|--user [DOMAIN/]USERNAME[%PASSWORD]] [-N|--no-pass]
      [--password=STRING] [-A|--authentication-file FILE] [-P|--machine-pass]
      [--simple-bind-dn=STRING] [-k|--kerberos STRING] [-V|--version]
      [--uninstall] [--reinstall] [--system]
      [--runas=[DOMAIN\]USERNAME%PASSWORD] [--runas-file=FILE]
      [--interactive=0|1] [--ostype=0|1|2] //host command
```

Answer (score 1):

The Windows account is locked. If you are on a Domain network, Check "Active Directory users and computers" for the user account in question and make sure you unlock the account.

If you are NOT on a domain, You will need to go to the windows computer that is hosting the account and unlock the account. To do so perform the following:

- Start > Run > Compmgmt.msc > Enter
- Expand Local users and groups
- Located the user, Double click it and unlock it.

Hope this helps.